# on the fly FTP mirror using Apache/Php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ftp, mirroring

I got data on a private FTP server I want to mirror it, but "on demand".
My frontend is an Apache/PHP server...

Here's the flow :

- Clients asks the apache server for a file
- if file is not on hdd, download it from the ftp server. (stream it to client, while saving it to hdd)
- send file to client (from apache)

I don't know exactly how to proceed...

Is there a way to stream a file while downloading it ?

Maybe we could do something with php/curl...

Comment: The question is unclear; should the clone be initiated by a request on the primary server, or the secondary server, or either ? From where to where should it be cloned - from a dedicated FTP server to a web server, or vice versa ? Enumerate the actors and provide a clear flow description.

Answer (score 0):

Try LftpFS: http://lftpfs.sourceforge.net/

It's a FUSE filesystem that relies on lftp as a backend and does exactly what you need. It requires a basic lftp script, but it's easy to write one. The [official site](http://lftp.yar.ru/) provides sufficient info.

You can also try and turn your Apache into a caching proxy, that would work too (and probably faster than FUSE).